# Azure Media Player Integration in Android app

Tags: android, azure, http-live-streaming

I have a Url encrypted using Azure Media Services. Now I want to play the Url in my android app.My doubt is ,Do we can use any player to play the encyrpted Url ? Or we have to use only Azure Media player to play that Url ? If so,How I can integrate Azure Media Player in my android app.? Please give me a clear documentation on integration.

Comment: If *A good document is not available in google* then it doesn't exist ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the encrypted url you said is. Is it a streaming url for an encrypted media?

As I know, there are many existing player which you can select to play the media content using Azure Media Services, please see the details from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-playback-content-with-existing-players). And you can [embed a MPEG-DASH Adaptive Streaming Video in an HTML5 Application with DASH.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-embed-mpeg-dash-in-html5).

Meanwhile, you can try to follow the offical [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-develop-video-players) to develop your own vedio player application to consume streaming media from Azure Media Services in different platform like android as you wish. Just follow the offical workflow as below.

[image]